# Should I use the new C++11 'auto' feature, especially in loops?

Tags: c++, c++11

What are the pros/cons to using the `auto` keyword, especially in for loops?

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++ )
{
   it->something();
}

for(std::map<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++ )
{
   it->second->something();
}

for(auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++ )
{
   it->??
}
```

Seems like if you don't know whether you have an iterator for a map or a vector you wouldn't know whether to use `first` or `second` or just directly access properties of the object, no?

This reminds me of the C# debate on whether to use the keyword `var`.  The impression I'm getting so far is that in the C++ world people are ready to adopt the `auto` keyword with less of a fight than `var` in the C# world.   For me my first instinct is that I like to know the type of the variable so I can know what operations I can expect to perform on it.

Comment: Wait! There was a fight about whether to use `var`? I missed that.

Comment: Even better, you can just use `for (auto& it : x)` (or without reference if you want copying)

Comment: Seems to me if you're writing a loop to iterate over the contents of `x` and you don't even know what `x` is, you shouldn't write that loop in the first place ;-)

Comment: @fish: range based for-loops rules, but I would have been pedantic and done: 'for (T& it : x)' instead when using range based for-loops, as I feel using auto there is less informative. Kind of a misuse of auto in my mind.

Comment: The fight over using var was a little silly, especially in retrospect. See [Cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 41):

The motivations in C++ are more extreme, as types can become vastly more convoluted and complex than C# types due to metaprogramming and other things. `auto` is faster to write and read and more flexible/maintainable than an explicit type. I mean, do you want to start typing

```
boost::multi_map<NodeType, indexed_by<ordered_unique<identity<NodeType>>, hashed_non_unique<identity<NodeType>, custom_hasher>>::iterator_type<0> it
```

That's not even the full type. I missed off a couple template arguments.

Comment: +1 for the example, but that also tells something about the state of "modern" C++.

Comment: @zvrba: Yeah- that the generic facilities are much more powerful than C#'s.

Comment: that's what typedef is for

Comment: @gbjbaanb No, that’s what `auto` is for. By design. `typedef` helps, but `auto` helps more.

Comment: typedef invalidates the argument that "not using auto makes for really long types"

Answer (score 29):

In your example:

```
for(auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
{
  it->??
}
```

there has to be a declaration for `x` visible.  Therefore the type of `it` should be obvious.  If the type of `x` isn't obvious, then the method is too long, or the class is too large.

Comment: Also, `x` is a very bad variable name for a container. In some situations you can most likely just look at the (semantically valuable) name and infer the possible operations.

Comment: @Max: only used `x` as an generic example, I tend to use quite descriptive variable names.

Comment: @User Of course, I didn't assume that was a real-world example ;)

Answer (score 14):

**Objection**! Loaded question.

Can you explain to me why the third code has `??` in it, yet the first and second don’t? For fairness’ sake, your code *must* read as follows:

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
{
   it->???
}

for(std::map<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
{
   it->second->???
}
```

There. Same problem even though you didn’t use `auto`.

And in all cases, the answer is the same: **Context matters**. You can’t meaningfully talk about a piece of code in isolation. Even if you hadn’t used templates but some concrete type, this would only have moved the problem somewhere else, since the reader of your code would have to know about the declaration of said type.

If use of `auto` in those situations render your code unreadable you should treat this as a warning sign that there’s something wrong with your code design. Of course, there are cases where low-level details matter (such as when dealing with bit operations or legacy API) in which cases an explicit type might aid readability. But in general – no.

Regarding `var` (since you explicitly mentioned it), there’s also a [vast consensus](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203203938/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx) in the C# community *for* using `var`. Arguments against its use are generally [built on fallacies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41514/1968).

Comment: I think the point was, with auto you dont know what that you put next...   is it  your code specific "something" or is it a data type related unpacking to get to your data object that has the method "something"

Comment: @Ptolemy And my point is: in the other two codes you *also* don’t know (generally) what to put next: `T` is as opaque to the user as `auto`. Yet one is supposed to be fine and the other not?! That doesn’t make sense. In the case of OP, `T` is a stand-in for an arbitrary type. In real code, it may be the use of templates `(for typename std::vector<T>::iterator…)` or a class interface. In both cases, the actual type is hidden from the user, and yet we routinely write such code without issues.

Comment: Actually, yes you do.  If its a vector, you know that you need to do -> and then you have access to your data type.  If its a map, you know you need to do ->second-> and then you have access to your data type, if its auto, you don't know what you need to do to get access to your data type.  You seem to be confusing the "what is the data type contained in the STL collection" with "which STL collection type do we have".  auto makes this problem worse.

Comment: @Ptolemy All these arguments are just as true when using `auto`. It’s trivial to see what operations `x` supports from context. In fact, the type gives you *no* additional information: in either case you need some secondary (IDE , documentation, knowledge/memory) to tell you the set of supported operations.

Comment: If I see  auto it = x.begin()  I need to look elsewhere to find out how to unpack 'it' to get to T.  If I see vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin()  I know I can get to T by doing it-> or *it

Comment: @Ptolemy That is *only* true if you are in the highly convoluted situation that you don’t know what `begin` returns but you *do* know what `std::vector<>::iterator` is. And you need to use a bad programming tool that cannot give you this information trivially. This is highly convoluted. In reality, you either know both `begin` and `iterator` or neither, and you should be using an IDE or editor that can readily make the relevant information available to you. Every modern IDE and programming editor can do that.

Comment: This "highly convoluted situation" arises every time you are doing a bug fix on someone else's code that they wrote 6 months ago. In other words, it happens all the time to everyone else reading your code.  but not to you whilst you are writing the auto code everywhere.

Comment: @Ptolemy You're admitting that you're working on code that you don't fully understand. *That* is the real problem, not the use of auto.

Comment: I am admitting to being a professional software developer that has worked on a significant number of projects over the years.  Some greenfield, and some with 15+ years of code history.  Anything that improves clarity of the code is a bonus.  Long complicated STL variable declarations work against that, but auto 'solves' that problem just by moving it else where.  Make your code obvious is the best thing any developer does.  I would rather code was obvious, but wrong, than convoluted and correct, as obvious code will get fixed, convoluted code will get broken.

Comment: @Ptolemy I entirely agree. The only thing I disagree with its that I think `auto` *improves* clarity (in most cases) and helps making code simpler and more obviously correct. I'm not against explicit type annotations in general, incidentally (on the contrary). But in function local context I've rarely found them helpful.

Answer (score 11):

### PRO

Your code :

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
```

is not going to compile, because of the template dependent name.

This is the correct syntax :

```
for( typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
```

Now look how long the type declaration is. This tells why the `auto` keyword was introduced. This :

```
for( auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
```

is more concise. So, this is a pro.

---

### CON

You have to be a bit careful. With the keyword `auto`, you get the type you declared.

For example :

```
std::vector< int > v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for ( auto it : v )
{
  ++ it;   // ops modifying copies of vector's elements
}
```

vs

```
std::vector< int > v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for ( auto & it : v )   // mind the reference
{
  ++ it;   // ok, vector's elements modified
}
```

---

To conclude : yes, you should it, but not overuse it. Some people tend to use it too much, and put auto everywhere, like in next example :

```
auto i = 0;
```

vs

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: `auto i = 0`. Guilty. I do that. But that's because I know that `0` is a literal of type `int`. (and an octal constant ;-) )

Answer (score 7):

YES, you should! `auto` does not erase the type; even if you "don't know" what `x.begin()` is, the compiler knows and will report an error if you try to use the type wrongly.  Also, it is not unusual to emulate `map` with a `vector<pair<Key,Value>>`, so the code using `auto` will work for both dictionary representations.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should use `auto` as a default rule. It has raw advantages over explicitly specifying the type:

- It does not make you type things the compiler is already aware of.
- It makes the type of variables "follow along" any change in return value types.
- Doing so, it prevents **silent introduction of implicit conversions  and slicing** in local variable initialization.
- It removes the need of some explicit type calculations in templates.
- It removes the need of naming return types with long names. (the ones you copy-paste from compiler diagnostics)

This is where you have a choice. There are also cases where you don't have a choice:

- It permits declaration of variables of unutterable types, like the type of a lambda.

Provided that you know exactly what `auto` does, it has no disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

You should use auto when you don’t care what exactly the type is. As an example, x.begin() will give me an iterator with exactly the right type, and auto it = x.begin() will create a variable with the exactly right type. I don’t care what the type is.

Or auto x = f(a); auto y = f(b); Now i know that x, y have the correct type. Not bigger or smaller than needed. Do I care what exactly the type is? If you don’t, use auto.